# Given three non-overlapping circles, can we construct (via straightedge and compass) the triangle of minimum perimeter with one vertex on each circle?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

G. Polya "Mathematics and plausible reasoning"
Chapter 9, problem 2:

> Three circles in a plane, exterior to each other, are given in
>   position. Find the triangle with minimum perimeter that has one vertex
>   on each circle.

From the contents of the chapter it is obvious (using **light reflections** on three circular mirrors and **rubber band** methods) that the two sides of the required triangle that meet in a vertex on a given circle include *equal angles* with the radius.

> But how can we *construct* (with the compass and straightedge) these vertices (A,B,C)?

[image]

**UPD**
Let one of the circles be an infinite radius (*a straight line*):

[image]
Looks like the same solution... And no idea about construction.
So let *all of the circles* be an infinite radius:
[image]
And we get [Fagnano's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagnano%27s_problem) with clear construction.
Hope this will be useful (?)

Comment: Setting it differently, is the common point of $AD, BE, CF$ constructible by straightedge and compass ? You must know that there are many cases of remarkable points that are not contructible by straightedge and compass...

Comment: @Jean Marie, such a case is possible! But I would also like to prove this, at least heuristically, in the spirit of Polya's book.

Comment: @lesobrod:  I have already drawn the triangle $PQR$ in my comment and it applies to all circles with arbitrary radii. So I am certain that this  generalization with Fagnano's triangle (when the the straight lines are replaced by an arena of 3 circles) would hold good in the sought future solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Solution minimum triangle is determined by the given circles and angle bisectors.The following states that triangle $ABC$ has minimum perimeter for all triangles such as $EDF.$ Co-tangential circles are also included to suggest a set of problems with same inner minimum  perimeter triangle $ABC$.

[image: Comment]

EDIT1/2:

[image: In-Center based Construction]

Intersections of angle bisectors from vertices $(A,B,C) $ with given circles form  triangle $PQR$ vertices of minimum perimeter length.  This results  from the ellipse property... constancy of major axis length between shown ellipse foci with their mirror  reflective property considered pairwise among $(P,Q,R)$.

Comment: Thank you for your diagram. I don't understand your construction, though: how are $A, B$ and $C$ determined? Or, to put it another way, how is $I$ determined? (Once $I$ is found, it's easy to find $A, B$ and $C$.)

Comment: @Rosie F May: The three given non-overlapping circles are centered at $(A,B,C)$

Comment: @user: No. It may be for special cases like three given circles of same radius and when their centers are placed at vertices of given equilateral triangle.

Comment: Thank you for your second diagram. That answers the question in my earlier comment. (Note that in the first diagram and my comment, the centres are $D, E, F$ and the vertices are $A, B, C$, but in the second diagram, the centres are $A, B, C$ and the vertices are $P, Q, R$.) Further question: do the angle-bisectors in the second diagram also show the vertices of that triangle of *greatest* perimeter with one vertex on each circle?

Comment: @user: In-center $I$ of $ABC$  need have no relation to any center of inner triangle $PQR$.

Comment: I do not think that your solution  is correct. As absolutely convincing argued in the question the lines $AI, BI,CI $ have to be angle bisectors in the triangle $PQR$, not in $ABC$.

Comment: Seems to be a compromise it appears.  Is it possible to define a configuration on the basis you mention?

Comment: I think the constructibility of the point is the central question of the exercise as was mentioned in a comment to OP. In any case the algebraic equation for the point is very complicated.

Comment: Does Fermat point appeal to you?

Answer (score 1):

*-- As addendum to Narasimham's answer --*

Consider $A$ and $C$ fixed.
Then for the perimeter to be minimum, $B$ shall lie on the ellipse with foci
in $A$ and $C$, minimal sum of the distances from them, so on the one tangent to the 
circle through $B$.

By the property of elliptical mirror, the normal to the tangent in $B$, shall halve the angle $ABC$.

Then the proof of Narasimham's answer follows.

Moreover, with $A$ and $C$ fixed, we are minimizing $p$,  and $p-b$ as well.
By symmetry, the triangle has also minimal area.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but rather an extended comment.*

As easy to understand the construction boils down to finding the in-center $I$ of the triangle $ABC$.

An algebraic way for this could be the following. Let the coordinates and the radius of $i$-th circle ($i=1,2,3$) be $(x_i,y_i)$ and $r_i$, respectively, and the coordinates of the point $I$ be ($x,y$).
Then the coordinates of the vertex $A$ read:
$$
(x_A,y_A)=(x_1,y_1)+r_1\frac{(x-x_1,y-y_1)}{\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}},\tag1
$$
and similarly for the vertices $B$ and $C$.

From the condition that $I$ is the in-center of $\triangle ABC$ we have the following equations to determine $(x,y)$:
$$
\frac{\frac{x-x_A}{x_B-x_A}-\frac{y-y_A}{y_B-y_A}}
{\sqrt{\frac1{(x_B-x_A)^2}+\frac1{(y_B-y_A)^2}}}=
\frac{\frac{x-x_B}{x_C-x_B}-\frac{y-y_B}{y_C-y_B}}
{\sqrt{\frac1{(x_C-x_B)^2}+\frac1{(y_C-y_B)^2}}}=
\frac{\frac{x-x_C}{x_A-x_C}-\frac{y-y_C}{y_A-y_C}}
{\sqrt{\frac1{(x_A-x_C)^2}+\frac1{(y_A-y_C)^2}}},\tag2
$$
where $x_A,y_A,x_B,y_B,x_C,y_C$ are to be substituted using (1).

After expanding the equations one should end up with a system of two polynomial equation for $(x,y)$ of a rather high order. It is probable that the solution to this equation is not constructible.

Answer (score 0):

One more attempt:

If a triangle vertices are given, then the *Fermat-Toricelli point* $F$ that sees its sides isogonally $@\measuredangle\pi/3$ minimizes sum of lengths from $F$ to vertices $(A,B,C)$.

*Conversely* ,$(P,Q,R)$ can be slid anywhere along the radial lines $ (OA,OB,OC)$ with minimum peripheral length $2s$ with given total length of spokes.

i.e.,any triangle enclosed around the hexagonal Fermat node $F$ should  minimize peripheral length sum $PQR$ as shown with required $ (AP,BQ,CR)$ radial offsets.

[image: Fermat Pt Logic]

This solution is built on [Fig2 Fermat Point Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) reference.

Comment: From the construction it is obvious that $F$ is Fermat point both for $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle PQR$. But we are looking for the in-center of $\triangle PQR$, which generally does not coincide with the Fermat point (except for equilateral triangle).

Comment: Not considering any  in-center in the Fermat point option.

Comment: Previously the construction was around  the in-center, and now a fresh  approach is adopted around the Fermat point. Upto now it appears both are incorrect !